# Java Scanner - While Loop not continuing

Tags: java

I'm running a bit of code to read data from a file and then split each line into an array for easier calculating.

However, I've come across a problem where my while loop isn't continuing despite the fact I know there is more data in the text file.

Any help with the problem would be greatly appreciated!

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = null;
    Scanner sc = null;

    String file_name = "data.txt";

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file_name);
        sc = new Scanner(fr);


        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            int year = 0;
            int month = 0;
            double sales_total = 0;
            String lines[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                int value = Integer.valueOf(lines[i]);
                if (value > 2000) {
                   year = value;
                }
                else if (i == 1){
                    month = value;
                }
                else {
                    sales_total += value;
                }
                System.out.println(sales_total);
            }
            System.out.println(year + " - " + month + " - "+sales_total);
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
    finally {
        if (fr != null) { fr.close();}  
        if (sc != null) { sc.close();}
    }
}
```

data.txt

```
2016 02 5 18 12
2016 12  14  10   3   5   6   8  20   7  10  
2016 09  17   3  16  18  19  10   6  10  
2016 10   5   3  12   4  12  15  
2016 11  18  19  16   2   
2017 01   5   5   4  11
2017 02  41   3
2017 06   3   6  18 
2017 07  15  18  15  12   9  15
2017 11   9   8   9   4  20  20  19   3 
2018 01  19  19   3  10  20  20  18  14   3   
2017 12   8  13  18   6   
2018 11  10   2  11   8  17   8   6  18  15   1
```

Comment: Please provide small sample input file

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Right now it's just your word against the JVM's.

Comment: Apologies! I have now updated the OP with the contents of the sales-data.txt file.

Comment: Does the code throw any exception?

Comment: It was throwing the following exception... ```java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""```

I fixed this by checking for multiple spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sc.nextLine and sc.hasNextLine are blocking calls by design, so it will remain blocking until new input comes in. see [Scanne.hasline() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())

Could it be that some lines in code are missing CR LF delimiter?
I took you sample, opened it with notepad++ and viewed the whitespace (under view->show symbol). and saw the following:

```
...
2017 11   9   8   9   4  20  20  19   3 CR LF
2018 01  19  19   3  10  20  20  18  14   3 CR LF  
2017 12   8  13  18   6   CR LF
2018 11  10   2  11   8  17   8   6  18  15   1
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It was the spacing in between the integers in the data file.

I changed the exception format around and it was throwing the following exception

```java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""```

I fixed this by checking for multiple spaces or tabs with the following bit of code.

```String lines[] = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");```